# Listening to Java logger

Tags: java, logging

I am trying to listen to a Java logger, and I'm not quite sure how to go about it.

```
 <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

  <root level="DEBUG">
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    <!-- <appender-ref ref="ROLLING" /> -->
    <logger name="org.jooq" level="DEBUG"/>
  </root>
```

Theoretically something is piping to STDOUT? How do I listen to the error messages?

I am trying to troubleshoot something and want to see what error gets thrown.

Would I just find the PID of the specific process and listen to it?

The processes I am seeing are:

```
PID   USER     TIME   COMMAND
    1 root       0:00 sh ./entrypoint.sh
    5 root      22:56 java -Xmx768m -Xms768m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=/dump/ -Dninja.external.configuration=application.conf -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xm
 6592 root       0:00 /bin/bash
 6683 root       0:00 ps
```

Comment: How are you running the app? That will determine where stdout goes.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to log also error messages?, if that is so then replace:
 `<logger name="org.jooq" level="DEBUG"/>` with:
 `<logger name="org.jooq" level="ERROR"/>` you can use level="ALL" to log everything

Comment: Yes, but how do I listen to it? Just cat-ing the PID?

Comment: but, why would you like to listen to the process?, cant you just read the error logged? or maybe log to a file?